# Bulk blocking of specific email addresses

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010, outlook-2010

I have a small group of users who have a large amount of addresses added as blocked senders in Outlook.  They have asked if I can stop these senders from getting into their mailbox (or more specifically their junk folder).  As most Exchange/Outlook admins will know you can export this list to a text file.  My initial thought (as I am loathe to lower the SCL within Exchange or Mail Security,) is to use something like the following after aggregating the addresses.

```
$blockedSenders=Get-Content -Path <Path of file> | Set-SenderFilterConfig -BlockedSenders $blockedSenders
```

My question is, is this the most efficient way of handling the problem (I do not know if the senders are spam or the users just don't want to get mail from them,) or am I overlooking a more obvious solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About that PowerShell snippet: You're assigning ***and*** piping at the same time. And you're doing it wrong. Those are two separate statements:

```
$BlockedSenders = Get-Content .\blockedsenders.txt
Set-SenderFilterConfig -BlockedSenders $BlockedSenders
```

---

About the larger problem at hand:
You need the users to specify which ones are sending spam, and which ones they simply don't care for.

What you are effectively intending to do, is blocking mails from those senders for *the entire organization*, instead of just for those users who have actively blocked them for their own mailboxes.

I'm not sure I can divert further into whether you are overlooking an obvious solution. An obvious solution to what exactly?